# WebDispatchFormatter ignoring "Accepts" HTTP Headers

Tags: .net, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I have a WCF project in VS2010, .NET 4. I'm using WcfRestContrib in order to support multiple seamless formatters for my service calls. This isn't working. I am able to submit a query with a JSON payload, but I can't get it to automatically return JSON data in the response. I'm using the "Accepts" HTTP Header and setting it to "application/json" - just as I've mapped the mime type in the config below.

The only way I can get JSON to come back in the response is to set the `system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceeBehaviors/behavior[@name='REST']/webFormatter/formatters/@defaultMimeType` attribute to "application/json". This proves that the WebDispatchFormatter is certainly involved in the output, it's just not using the Accept HTTP header to determine which formatter to use.

**How can I get the WebDispatchFormatter to look at the Accept HTTP Header?** I was under the impression that this was the default behavior.

I've configured the service to use WcfRestContrib's WebDispatchFormatter in my Web.config file as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="webFormatter" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Configuration.WebDispatchFormatter.ConfigurationBehaviorElement, WcfRestContrib" />
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>

    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="REST"/>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="REST">
                <webHttp automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/> <!-- Note: I also tried it with automaticFormatSelectionEnabled set to "false". -->
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>

        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="REST">
                <webFormatter>
                    <formatters defaultMimeType="application/xml">
                        <formatter mimeTypes="application/xml,text/xml" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.PoxDataContract, WcfRestContrib" />
                        <formatter mimeTypes="application/json" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.DataContractJson, WcfRestContrib" />
                        <formatter mimeTypes="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" type="WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.Formatters.FormUrlEncoded, WcfRestContrib" />
                    </formatters>
                </webFormatter>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
        <service name="MyService.REST" behaviorConfiguration="REST">
            <endpoint name="REST" contract="MyService.IREST" bindingConfiguration="REST" behaviorConfiguration="REST" binding="webHttpBinding" />
        </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

My service interface/contract looks like this.

```
namespace MyService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public partial interface IREST
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method="POST")]
        [WebDispatchFormatter(WcfRestContrib.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.WebDispatchFormatter.FormatterDirection.Outgoing)]
        List<MyData> GetData(SearchQuery searchQuery);
    }
}
```

My service implementation looks like this:

```
namespace MyService
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    public partial class REST : IREST
    {
        public List<MyData> GetData(SearchQuery searchQuery)
        {
            return GetTheData(searchQuery);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know your what your current development investment is in using the WCF Web API but you should be aware that it is [on its way to being deprecated](https://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP). If you're starting a new project with WCF Web API definitely use ASP.NET Web API instead, it's a much better framework for creating HTTP API's.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using `Accepts` instead of `Accept` as the HTTP header key! Whoops!